# Telegram Bot Удалить сообщение пользователя

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Использую pyTelegramBotAPI , там есть функция delete_message.
Пишу:

```
bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

Сообщение удаляется, но только то, которое сам бот отправил пользователю.

Как удалить сообщение, которое отправил пользователь?
\

- интересует вопрос, возможно ли редактировать сообщение(вроде edit_message), которое прислал сам пользователь, а не сообщение, которое отправил бот?

К примеру: Если пользователь отправит /test или test, то удалить это сообщение.

Такие варианты не работают:

1)

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def handler_test(message):
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)`
```

2. 

```
if message.text == "test":
   bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

Comment: Зачем Вам редактировать сообщения от лица бота? Кто-то смотреть будет?
На крайний случай отправляйте корректные сообщения, чтобы ничего не исправлять

Comment: К примеру, чтобы получить доступ к команде, бот запрашивает пароль. И этот пароль может увидеть любой, кто возьмет это устройство в руки.

Comment: [решение](https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline) Вашей проблемы по утечке информации

Comment: А тестировалась ли такая реализация в группе, где боту присвоен статус "Админ" ? Возможно при диалоге с ботом он и удаляет Ваше сообщение, но только для себя.

Comment: Mr Morgan: Это скорее обходной путь, а не решение.

Comment: madhattermonroe: В группе/каналах, я предполагаю, скорее всего, это будет работать, но тут задача состоит именно в том, возможно ли, удалить сообщение пользователя именно в прямом чате с ботом.

Comment: @BladzheR Насколько я понимаю, возможности удалять "для всех" чужие сообщения в диалогах Телеграмом не предусмотрено.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В диалоге бот никак не сможет удалить сообщения пользователя (представьте, что ваш собеседник удаляет ваши же сообщения). А для группового чата нужно просто дать боту права администратора + разрешение на удаление сообщений.

С редактированием точно так же.

Answer (score 1):

Бот должен быть Админом, чтобы удалять чужие сообщения

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1
Если бот используется персонально (личные сообщения) - бот удаляет **только** собственные сообщения.

Вариант 2
Если бот используется в групповых сообществах (группы/супергруппы) - бот может удалить любые сообщения доступные по API TG

Попробуй оставить функцию удаления сообщений и если кто-то добавит твоего бота в группу, то будет работать функция удаления сообщений пользователя