# Авто удаление сообщение Telegram бот

Tags: telegram-bot

Есть ли метод который удаляет сообщение бота через запланированное время?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/781253/319165 забавно что проблема этого юзера частично является вашим решением

Comment: Я знаю как удалить сообщение. Но меня интересует, есть ли функция по типу таймера на удаление